# API which I designed to generate jwt on nodejs returns config.data (contains user submit data including password). How to stop it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, jwt

This is the app.js. Here the api end point is http://localhost:3001/api/male/users/signup. Here I use mongoose, express to design the backend.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const maleproductRoutes = require('./api/routes/male/products');
const maleorderRoutes = require('./api/routes/male/orders');
const maleauthRoutes = require('./api/routes/male/users');

const femaleproductRoutes = require('./api/routes/female/products');
const femaleorderRoutes = require('./api/routes/female/orders');
const femaleauthRoutes = require('./api/routes/female/users');

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://'+process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_USER+':'+process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW+'@clusteretailor.extk1.mongodb.net/'+process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_DB+'?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});

// Routes which should handle requests
app.use('/api/male/products', maleproductRoutes);
app.use('/api/male/orders', maleorderRoutes);
app.use('/api/male/users', maleauthRoutes);

app.use('/api/female/products', femaleproductRoutes);
app.use('/api/female/orders', femaleorderRoutes);
app.use('/api/female/users', femaleauthRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("Not found");
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: error.message
    }
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is the signup controller of the endpoint. I generate the JWT here and send response in body. But I don't mention anything regarding the submit data. I have no idea why the response contains the user submitted data which is unnecessary.

```
[const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const User = require("../../models/male/user");
router.post("/signup", (req, response, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length >= 1) {
        return response.status(409).json({
          message: "Mail exists"
        });
      } else {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) {
            return response.status(500).json({
              error: err
            });
          } else {
            const user = new User({
              _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
              email: req.body.email,
              password: hash
            });
            user
              .save()
              .then(result => {

                const token = jwt.sign(
                  {
                    email: result.email,
                    userId: result._id
                  },
                  process.env.JWT_KEY,
                  {
                    expiresIn: "1h"
                  }
                );
                return response.status(201).json({
                  message: "Auth successful",
                  token: token
                });
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                response.status(500).json({
                  error: err
                });
              });
          }
        });
      }
    });
});

router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length < 1) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user\[0\].password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed"
          });
        }
        if (result) {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              email: user\[0\].email,
              userId: user\[0\]._id
            },
            process.env.JWT_KEY,
            {
              expiresIn: "1h"
            }
          );
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Auth successful",
            token: token
          });
        }
        res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});

router.delete("/:userId", (req, res, next) => {
  User.remove({ _id: req.params.userId })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "User deleted"
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});

// get all male users
router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  User.find()
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
      console.log(docs);
      //   if (docs.length >= 0) {
      res.status(200).json(docs);
      //   } else {
      //       res.status(404).json({
      //           message: 'No entries found'
      //       });
      //   }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

when I console.log response of the api in frontend it shows config.data as below. which is unnecessary. Only what I need is data object, not config.data.

```
data: "{"email":"ggd@gmail.com","password":"dasdfdsvcsdv","gender":"male"}"
```

Comment: maybe the problem comes from client side (you might have logged the wrong object). Can you post the response handler code on frontend?

Comment: Could there be a router or middleware part in the express server that is simply echoing the submitted body back to the client? Maybe in the main module where the server actually starts listening on port 3001 for incoming messages?